# Откуда брать include-файлы для TableGen (LLVM)?

Tags: компиляция, компилятор, cmake, llvm

Хочу написать свой LLVM-бэкенд. Основной TableGen-файл (`Abc.td`) начинается со строки:

```
include "llvm/Target/Target.td"
```

Когда пытаюсь его скомпилировать (`llvm-tblgen src/Abc.td`), пишет следующее:

```
src/Abc.td:1:9: error: Could not find include file 'llvm/Target/Target.td'
include "llvm/Target/Target.td"
        ^
```

Однако без `llvm/Target/Target.td` нельзя наследоваться от таких классов как `InstrInfo`, `AsmParser` etc.

Подглядел где-то на гитхабе сборку TableGen-файлов через CMake с помощью команды `tablegen` (и подумал, что, может, она умеет подключать `llvm/**/*.td` файлы), но мой CMake о ней не знает:

```
Unknown CMake command "tablegen".
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятно нужно указать где искать файлы для импорта:

```
llvm-tblgen src/Abc.td -I=$(LLVM_SRC)/include/llvm/Target/
```

где `$(LLVM_SRC)` это директория в которой лежат исходники LLVM.

Comment: у меня к вам странная просьба, не могли бы вы взглянуть на этот вопрос : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50308253/creating-local-variable-in-function-llvm